# How to get destination info when using iptables to redirect packets?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I want to make a transparent/global VPN. And I know redirection of packets is helpful. In this post:[Configuring Ubuntu for Global SOCKS5 proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/332473/configuring-ubuntu-for-global-socks5-proxy) , Khaled suggests to use iptables to redirect packets. But what I wonder is how the proxy knows the destination -- destination IP and remote server port . Since if the proxy listens on tcp layer, the destination info is lost. Is there someone knows how to get the destination info ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw an function `getdestaddr` in redir.c of project `shadowsocks-libev`, it uses getsockopt (sock_fd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, sockaddr_ptr, socklen_ptr). It solves destination for TCP. But it doesn't work for udp, so what about udp ?